# Access application resources in WPF User Control Library

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF user control library project.
In this same project I have a resource file, and I include it in my user control resources like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Globals.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How can I access this resource from code behind?
When I try to access Application.Current.Resources it is empty.

Thanks

EDIT:
I realized this is because the resource is member of the user control and not a member of the application. (In the user control library project I can't add resources in the application level).

But, because I am using MVVM I don't have acces from my viewmodel to the user control, so how can I reach the style in the user control's resource?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this worked for me:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibraryNamespace;component/rdImages.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibraryNamespace;component/rdColorImages.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/rdStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/rdStringResourceEN.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

First two resource dictionaries are from external library (Styles, Drawing Brushes), last two are local (included in my project - Styles, Strings).

Comment: In the user control library project i dont have a app.xaml file and cannot declare resources in the application level

Comment: In my case I was accessing a resource from the same project but it fails because I have a WPF library used in the project. Solution was to have:
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
in the App.xaml before defining the Style(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the styles like

```
Style style = Application.Current.FindResource("ResourceName") as Style;
```

where 'ResourceName' is from 'Styles/Globals.xaml'

Comment: I tried that but it does not work! it works ok in a regular 
WPF project , but not in the user control library project